# BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter is allowing the request when Authorization token is not present in the request

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I am extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and adding the OAuth2 authorization for the app to app communication. If I provide a wrong token or expired token, I am getting the failure response. But if I dont provide an Authorization header, then it is not failing.

```
http.authorizeRequests().
            mvcMatchers(path).hasAnyAuthority(...)
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().
            jwt();
```

I can see that the below code inside the BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter which may be the reason the no token scenario is not failing

```
if (token == null) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
```

How this scenario is usually handled.

Comment: ..the place is correct, the `return` also good(no authentication) , but that it "is not failing", one of the other filters  is responsible(!) ..So some other "filter" (in your config!), *must* grant access.

Comment: I am not configuring any other filter. Currently because of this the client is able to access the API if they are not providing any Authorization header. Are you suggesting that I may need to write another filter to fail this. Mostly I am looking to understand the general practice among those who are using OAuth2 and are faced the similar scenario

Comment: The authentication filters _should_ short circuit if there is nothing to authenticate. The user then ends up as anonymous so would have no “granted authorities” - this is where your misconfiguration likely is.

Comment: Besides you config (which "leaks"), it could also be the "browser"/a "session"(cookie/id)... (?)

Comment: @BoristheSpider, In my question, I also have added the code I am using. In that I have the hasAnyAuthority mentioned. What else I may need to add to handle this no token scenario. In my understanding from the token is what the Authorities are extracted. As the token itself is not there, what may be causing the access to be granted for the anonymous. Note that I actually dont have any real user, it is app to app communication with token generated to through client credentials